# How to merge two JSONField fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-jsonfield

Postgres allows merging/concatenating two JSONB fields into one. Quoting the [relevant Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

`jsonb || jsonb → jsonb` - Concatenates two jsonb values.

As far as I can see, the Django ORM does not provide an operator for this type of concatenation. [`django.db.models.expressions.Combinable`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2b688b966f5d30414899549412d370e1317ddb8/django/db/models/expressions.py#L36) does not have a `||` operator.

[`django.contrib.postgres.search.SearchQueryCombinable`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2b688b966f5d30414899549412d370e1317ddb8/django/contrib/postgres/search.py#L161) has a `||` operator, but this class does not seem to apply here.

How can I merge two JSONFields using Django functions, but without evaluating the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since expressions usually are of the mixin class `Combinable`, we can use the `_combine` method on an `F` field and customize the operator to be `||`. `ExpressionWrapper` is necessary because Django cannot infer the `output_field` of our customized combination.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F

class MyModel(models.Model):
    jsonfield1 = models.JSONField()
    jsonfield2 = models.JSONField()


MyModel.objects.annotate(
    concatenated_jsonfields=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("jsonfield1")._combine(F("jsonfield2"), "||", reversed=False),
        output_field=models.JSONField(),
    )
)
```